# Log some info after every 20 seconds, Java 1.4 only

Tags: java, timer

I have a loop, and it will take maybe an hour to complete.
In the loop I am inserting and updating records in a db, although I don't think that is relevant, but just in case.

Every 20 seconds or so I want to write an update to the db.
So I figure I need to make some time check at the beginning of the loop.
What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Any particular reason for Java 1.4 only? 1.6 has been out since 2006.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
final long interval = 20 * 1000;
long lastLogged = System.currentTimeMillis();
while (processing) {
  if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastLogged > interval) {
    lastLogged = System.currentTimeMillis();
    logToDatabase();
  }
  // do rest of processing
}
// Optionally:
logToDatabase();
```

Answer (score 2):

You could create a [TimerTask](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/TimerTask.html) and [schedule it](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Timer.html#scheduleAtFixedRate%28java.util.TimerTask,%20long,%20long%29) with a 20 second period.

Answer (score 1):

for timer issues i prefere to use Quartz framework. I don't think that the newest releases support for 1.4 but maybe early releases. You can create Jobs, Triggers, even with cron expressions. http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm.  Well if this is what you really want to do then you could do:

```
long time = System.currentTimeMillis();

for(;;) {

//doStuff

if((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) > 20000) {
  // log message
  time = System.currentTimeMillis();
}

}
```